# check user App Store wishlist

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there any possibility (using iOS SDK 6.x or 7.x) to check user App Store wishlist within third party app? I need that list in my app, but i can't find any informations about checking user app store data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***No***,There is no API within iOS(Public or Private) that can access this information. This is most likely because the iTunes and App Store apps are ***fancy*** websites with native extensions, therefore accessing this information would require direct access to Apple's servers. This is also a privacy concern as many users might not like third party apps to access their wish list.

Comment: Has this changed at all for iOS 8 or the soon to be released iOS 9?

Comment: No, this has no yet changed to my knowledge